# Pivot Table to fill pairs of observation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

The objective is to get a table with values of pair T1-T2. I have data in form of:

```
df
    T1  T2  Score
0   A   B   5
1   A   C   8
2   B   C   4
```

I tried:

```
df.pivot_table('Score','T1','T2')

    B   C       
A   5.0 8.0
B   NaN 4.0
```

I expected:

```
  A  B  C
A    5  8
B 5     4
C 8  4
```

So kind of like correlation table I think. Because A-B pair is same as B-A in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add all possible index with columns values by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with another `pivot` by swap `T1` and `T2` and last [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
idx = np.unique(df[['T1','T2']].values.ravel())
df1 = df.pivot_table('Score','T1','T2').reindex(index=idx, columns=idx)
df2 = df.pivot_table('Score','T2','T1').reindex(index=idx, columns=idx)

df = df1.combine_first(df2)
print (df)
      A    B    C
T1               
A   NaN  5.0  8.0
B   5.0  NaN  4.0
C   8.0  4.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table('Score','T1','T2')
df2 = df.pivot_table('Score','T2','T1')
common_val = np.intersect1d(df['T1'].unique(), df['T2'].unique()).tolist()

df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, on=common_val)

print(df)
     B    C    A
A  5.0  8.0  NaN
B  NaN  4.0  5.0
C  4.0  NaN  8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
In [11]: df1 = df.set_index(['T1', 'T2']).unstack(1)

In [12]: df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)

In [13]: df2 = df1.reindex(index=df1.index | df1.columns, columns=df1.index | df1.columns)

In [14]: df2.update(df2.T)

In [15]: df2
Out[15]:
     A    B    C
A  NaN  5.0  8.0
B  5.0  NaN  4.0
C  8.0  4.0  NaN
```